# Get selected text of dropdown menu without submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have this drop down menu:

```
if(isset($_POST['ss'])){$_SESSION['ss'] = $_POST['ss'] ;}else{$_SESSION['ss'] = 'English';}


<select name = "selectlang" class="selectlang" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option  value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=english' <?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "English"){echo ' selected="selected"' ;} ?>>English</option>
        <option  value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=swedish' <?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "Swedish"){echo ' selected="selected"' ;} ?>>Swedish</option>
        <option  value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=russian' <?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "Russian"){echo ' selected="selected"' ;} ?>>Russian</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="ss" id="lang_hidden" value="" />
```

this actually when I select one of languages it submit and added `?lang=.....` in the url link. And it works good, the url changes how ever the drop down menu is always English.

How can i make it changes also to selected language ?

I have used this but it didnt work.

```
$(".selectlang").change(function(){
var inpvalue = $('.selectlang option:selected').text();
    $("#lang_hidden").val(inpvalue).val();
   //$("#lang_hidden").closest('form').trigger('submit'); //(i will explain this)
  });
```

I explain that line above, when I uncomment it and add the form tags

```
  <form method="POST" action="">
 the above html code
  </form>
```

Well the dropdown menu keeps the selected language but dont change the link with `lang=.....` and pages not translated.

How can I manage them both to keep selected drop down menu text and get link changed?

Thanks in advance.

```
 //wanna see my function language so let me know.
```

my function language and where im making session variables maybe the error is here.

```
   function setlanguage(){
    //$_SESSION['selectlang'] = '';
    //if(!isset($_SESSION['selectlang'])){$_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English' ;}
    //if(!isset($_GET['lang'])){$_GET['lang'] = 'english' ;}
    if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
        switch ($_GET['lang']){
            case "english" :
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English';
                  include("lang/english.php");
                  break;
            case "swedish" :
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Swedish';
                   include("lang/swedish.php");
                   break;
            case "russian":
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Russian';
                   include("lang/russian.php");
                 break;

                }
        }
    else if(!isset($_GET['lang']) and isset($_SESSION['selectlang'])){
        switch ($_SESSION['selectlang']){
            case "English" :
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English';
                  include("lang/english.php");
                  break;
            case "Swedish" :
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Swedish';
                   include("lang/swedish.php");
                   break;
            case "Russian":
                    $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Russian';
                   include("lang/russian.php");
                 break;
            default :
                    include("lang/english.php");
        }
    }
    else{include("lang/english.php"); $_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'English';}

   }
```

Comment: I think You still need to redirect page. Are You sure You set up the session variable in php?

Comment: @Skriptotajs yes session variables are working good .

Comment: If want to redirect with your language selected then you also use HTML5
 `localStorage.setItem('lang', 'eng');` and get it after redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use different session variable names

in php

```
$_SESSION['selectlang'] = 'Russian';
```

in HTML

```
$_SESSION['ss'] == "Russian"
```

Comment: sorry i didnt post the last of that session , look exact before my form i edited now.

Comment: hehehe you was right :) , i puted this `$_SESSION['selectlang']` in my html dropdown and it worked :) .I thought ss will be for hidden input. Ok thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When You redirect page, if You are sure, You save the value to session variable, then the problem might be in letter case.

```
value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=english'
```

change

```
<?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "English"){echo ' selected="selected"' ;} ?>
```

to

```
<?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "english"){echo ' selected="selected"' ;} ?>
```

Comment: no , not this issue , letter cases are good, i have make session variables with big letters in beging

Comment: Well i think i must show where im making sessions , to let you know.w ill edit

Comment: @echo_Me - try with $_REQUEST['lang'] == "english"

Comment: with request didnt save selected dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below options.

```
 <option  value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=english' <?php if($_SESSION['ss'] == "english"){echo "selected" ;} ?>>English</option>

or 

 <option  value='<?php $website_link ?>?lang=english' <?php if($_REQUEST['lang'] == "english"){echo "selected" ;} ?>>English</option>
```

Comment: i think i must add my function to show sessiojn vars look edited question

Answer (score 0):

try this to change your url without page load.

```
pageurl = 'yourpage.php?lang=inpvalue;
if(pageurl!=window.location){
    window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
}
```

Comment: i must load page to get language file and translate page.